# PHP - Only Removing PHP tag from the string

Tags: php

I have a CMS where I let the user to upload JS and HTML code and I want them use all possible HTML tags, and only tags I want to restrict are `<PHP ?>` and `<? ?>`

I know we have `strip_tags` but it only have the option of allow tags. I want something similar but with the option of ban tags.

Thanks

Comment: It is Core PHP, not any particular framework or CMS

Comment: What about `preg_match`?

Comment: Do you need the content to be removed as well or just the tags?

Comment: Use HTML purifier. It gives you FAR better control over html sanitization than strip_tags ever will.

Comment: @TiiJ7, Also Content betwee the tags. THanks

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `<PHP` is not a PHP tag. That said, why do you even want to run the users code by the PHP parser? They could do anything. Use `file_get_contents` or `fread` instead of `require`/`include` and it'll never get parsed by PHP, and the end user will just see `I am hacker <?php file_put_contents('index.html', 'lolol n00b'); ?> hjahahaha`, and the user will simply feel dumb for trying.

Answer (score 1):

if the tags are only these, you can use `preg_replace` function:

```
$string = '<?php content ?>';
$string = preg_replace('/(<\?php|<\?|\?>)/i', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

it will output `content`

more information here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Downvoted, need to implement a better example, and the link should be only reference to what you are saying to avoid errors if the link goes dead

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $string='this string contains <?php tag';
 $string=str_replace('<?php','',$string);    // same can be done for '?>'
 echo $string;
?>
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/WZQ8z6hZ)**

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with strip tags as that function only handles html tags, and technically speaking, php open/close tags are not html.

What you could do is use a regular expression for simply matching the strings in context where they could mean something... It's a bit of a broad replace but not a terrible assumption that any tags in this format are meant to be open/close tags and can thus be filtered out:

```
$result = preg_replace('/<\?php|<\?|\?>/im', '', $content);
```

Comment: Oh. Goody... regexes on html... and on html that's probably full of nasty syntax errors because it's user-submitted as well. You might as well just have `$result = null` for more reliable results.

Comment: @MarcB that's not a regex over html [in order to parse and get content], that's just a way to prevent harmful code execution.

Comment: @MarcB nice rant but I believe it is a bit misplaced here... I don't see how regexing out those tags modifies html in any way. If preserving the original input is a goal then the files should be stored and served in a way it's never parsed by php, but that's besides the point...

Answer (score 0):

I first want to note that unless you are using [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), this shouldn't really be a problem, but anyway, my solution:

```
do {
    $content = preg_replace('/(<\\?.*?(\\?>|$))/si', '', $content, -1, $count);
} while($count);
```

If you're wondering why it's in a loop, it's because hackers can be quite ingenious: `<<? ?>?php`

This also removes the content between tags.

It will also remove other [Processing Instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) tags (like `<?xml`).